# How do I upgrade Nativescript to latest version?

Tags: nativescript

I've got {N} up and running along with an app I'm developing - including plug-ins.

I did a "tns info" and "npm outdated" and see I need to update. btw - what's the difference between the two.

Is there a command to download latest - including typescript.

What's babel-* and babylon - need that?

Comment: You could follow the instructions here - http://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions

Comment: Did that...but still babel, babylon, typescript and modules that I installed from npm are not current.

Comment: ok I was able to update my plugins (tns plugin update <name>) - now left with:  `babel-traverse
babel-types
babylon
nativescript-dev-typescript
typescript`